# Would data be in the same partition if I use composite keys ?

Tags: database, cassandra, batch-processing

Considere the following case regarding Cassandra database: I must perform a batch statement with some related data, e.g: table users and table users_by_username. I want to insert on user creation data on both tables. It's a transaction. In Cassandra documentation says the batch statement cannot reach multiple partitions. If I model the primary key as a composite key like following :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
  id text,
  tpe text,
  username text,
  PRIMARY KEY((tpe, id))
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_by_username(
  username text,
  tpe text,
  id text,
  PRIMARY KEY((tpe, username))
);
```

Example of rows:

user: ('1', 'users', 'lucasrpb')
user_by_username: ('lucasrpb', 'users', '1')

My doubt: will data be on the same partition to be able to do the batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitions are within a table, not across tables.  However, the **token** for data, which is used to identify which replicas will host the data, is based on the **partition** key (the first column in the primary key, or the first column(s) surrounded in parenthesis).

In your case, the **partition** key for 'user' is `(tpe, id)` and `user_by_username` is `(tpe, username)`.   Because of this, the token for the data will likely not be the same.

If the **primary** key for `user` was `(tpe, id)`, `user_by_username` `(tpe, username)`, the partition key for each case would be `tpe`, therefore granted `tpe` was the same, the token would be the same and therefore the data would be stored on the same replicas.

In any case, I would not recommend batching operations to update `user_by_username` and `user` together, but it'd be better in the case where the partition key was the same as less C* nodes need to be written to in the batch.

Since the only difference between your tables is your primary key, I think a good candidate for you if you are on a 3.0+ version would be to look into [materialized views](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views) which were introduced in 3.0.  With this you could set up a `user_by_username` view off of the `user` table like:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW user_by_username AS 
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE username IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY ((tpe, username));
```

This way you only have to make changes to `user`, which will then be propagated to `user_by_username` for you.

Comment: What would be the cost of this?

Comment: The cost of materialized views?   The performance considerations are documented well here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/materialized-view-performance-in-cassandra-3-x